# set session variable in Jquery

Tags: jquery, session, redirect

I am developing a login form. i want to verify username/password using JQuery (and PHP).

1) if usr/pwd is not correct, show message accordingly (without page refresh)

2) and if usr/pwd is correct 
   i) set session variable
   ii) redirect page

Comment: @loler - You've never heard of ajax i presume ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about php, but in asp.net I used jQuery ajax to access server method that would login user, set session variable and return response. Based on the response, jQuery would show appropriate message.

Here is a brief example of jQuery function:

```
$("#btnLogin").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "login.aspx/getDetails",
            data: "{uid:" + $("#txtUsername").val() + ", pass:"+$("#txtpassword").val()+"}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var response = eval("(" + data + ")");
                if (response.msg == "success") {
                    $("#message").text("Login successful");
                } else {
                   $("#message").text("Login failed");
                }
            }                
        });
    };
```